# Connected but no internet access in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet, network-manager, ifconfig, broadband

I have been using this broadband connection for a long time. Suddenly it stopped working, it shows "Connected DSL connection 1". But whenever I try to browse any website, it doesn't load and shows "Server not found". And I am pretty much sure there is nothing wrong with my ISP or broadband line cause I am using this same line in my Windows 8.

Actually I am not sure what to put in the terminal and what result I am supposed to paste here for fixing my connection. Somehow I figured it out that it might be helpful to run 'ifconfig'. The result is following...

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:3d:7e:32:f5:49  
      inet6 addr: fe80::d63d:7eff:fe32:f549/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:391 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:187744 (187.7 KB)  TX bytes:22183 (22.1 KB)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1857 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1857 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:142881 (142.8 KB)  TX bytes:142881 (142.8 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:172.16.10.22  P-t-P:172.16.10.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
      RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:58 (58.0 B)  TX bytes:68 (68.0 B)
```

1st ping output:   **ping -c 4 8.8.8.8**

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=92.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=98.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=114 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=102 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 92.383/102.060/114.698/8.155 ms
```

2nd ping output: **ping -c 4 google.com**

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Comment: You are connecting your computer directly to the modem? That's not a good idea.

Comment: Its an issue with Firefox had the same problem. You can still install in the terminal try using chrom

Comment: I have tried both chrome and firefox. But its not working. Also to make sure that there is no internet access in my system I have opened Software center. No change! @DnrDevil

Comment: Can u run updates in the terminal?

Comment: Nope. Is there anyway to reset the total network system? @DnrDevil

Comment: sudo service network-manager restart  (or) 

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: Could you please run the following two commands: First, run `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` (this is the ip adress of a google server). Then, run `ping -c 4 google.com`. Can you please post the output of those commands? This will determine if your whole internet connection does not work or maybe just your dns.

Comment: I have updated my question in response to your query. @Gasp0de

Answer (score 0):

In the Internet, every computer has an Address, just like houses in the real world. If you don't know where someone lives, but you do know his/her name, you call some service hotline (or look in the phonebook). In the Internet, the equivalent to this service/phonebook is called DNS, which means "Domain Name Service". You basically call this Domain Name Service, and ask them, hey, where does this PC named google.com live? In your case, your dns does not work (since you can ping google if you use its address, but not if you use the name).

**To solve this**, open the network manager, click on your connection, edit the settings (not really sure where to find the button in Ubuntu, in my network manager its in the lower right of the window). In the settings window, go to the IPv4 section. There is a field under DNS, in this field, enter 8.8.8.8. If you want, you can add another entry by clicking the plus, and in this field enter 8.8.4.4. Those are googles DNS servers and they should work pretty much all the time!

EDIT: If you cannot do as mentioned above, because you can't find the option or whatever, just run the following command:

`sudo sh -c "echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head"`

Comment: I was literally stuck with this problem whole day and needed to connect to internet. As I had no other option left, I had to reinstall my system. Anyway thanks for your explanation.